# Syntax error: Missing 'semicolon'

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Estaba creando un procedimiento pero me topé con un error al hacerla.

```
create procedure actualizar (in id int, in nom varchar(45), in corr 
varchar(45))
begin
update dpersona set nombre=nom, correo=corr where idpersona=id;
end
```

En la parte de `id` me manda

> Syntax error: Missing 'semicolon'

Comment: Primero prueba agregando ; al final, después del end. Si no funciona tienes que agregar DELIMITER // al inicio del todo y al final de todo // DELIMITER;   Ver: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio de mucho <3

Comment: He creado una respuesta con la traducción de lo que dice MySQL en la doc, para que pueda servir a otros que pudieren tener el mismo problema. Si consideras que la respuesta resuelve el problema la puedes marcar como solucionada. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error puede deberse a lo que indica MySQL en la documentación:

> Si utiliza el programa cliente mysql para definir un programa
>   almacenado que contiene caracteres de punto y coma, surge un problema.
>   De forma predeterminada, mysql reconoce el punto y coma como un
>   delimitador de instrucciones, por lo que debe redefinir el delimitador
>   temporalmente para que mysql pase toda la definición del programa
>   almacenado al servidor.
>
> Para redefinir el delimitador mysql, use el comando `DELIMITER`.  El
>   delimitador se cambia a `//` para permitir que toda la definición sea
>   pasada al servidor como una sola sentencia y luego restaurada a `;`
>   antes de invocar el procedimiento. Esto activa el delimitador `;`
>   utilizado en el cuerpo del procedimiento para ser pasado a través del
>   servidor en lugar de ser interpretado por el propio mysql.
>
> <sub>▸ Fuente: [Manual de Referencia de MySQL, *23.1 Defining Stored
>   Programs*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)</sub>

Ejemplo:

```
delimiter //
create procedure actualizar 
    (in id int, in nom varchar(45), in corr varchar(45))
begin
    update dpersona set nombre=nom, correo=corr where idpersona=id;
end
//
delimiter ;
```