# Error al crear trigger con phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Tengo un problema a la hora de crear un `trigger` en `phpmyadmin`. Esta es mi sintaxis en el campo definición:

```
DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';

IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ubicacion) THEN 
SELECT ubicacion INTO n_ubicacion FROM ubicacions WHERE id = NEW.id_ubicacion LIMIT 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO historico_equipos(usuario, id_equipo, estado, ubicacion, empleado, f_asignacion, created_at) VALUES (CURRENT_USER(), NEW.id, NEW.id_estado, n_ubicacion, NEW.id_empleado, NEW.f_asignacion, CURRENT_DATE())
```

No encuentro dónde está el problema. En phpmyadmin aparece el siguiente error:

Algo está equivocado en mi sintaxis cerca de:

```
DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT ''; IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ubicacion) THEN
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el error que te está generando?

Comment: #1064 Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca de: 'DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT ''; IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ub' en la linea 1

Comment: Creo que te falta pone al inicio de tu código `delimiter //`  y al final de la instrucción poner `delimiter;`, como se muestra en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68082/29967) a un tipo de error similar al tuyo.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE n_ubicacion VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';

IF (OLD.id_ubicacion <> NEW.id_ubicacion) THEN 
SELECT ubicacion INTO n_ubicacion FROM ubicacions WHERE id = NEW.id_ubicacion LIMIT 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO historico_equipos(usuario, id_equipo, estado, ubicacion, empleado, f_asignacion, created_at) 
VALUES (CURRENT_USER(), NEW.id, n_estado, n_ubicacion, n_completo, n_fecha, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
END
```

Añadí `BEGIN` y `END` e hice cambios con `;`.

Gracias.