# DECLARE syntax-error en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo este error que tiene que ver con el `declare`, y traté de muchas maneras, pero no puedo corregirlo:

```sql
declare '@i' int
set @i = 1

while @i <=10 -- 1.000.000 filas    
begin    
  insert into neptuno.varchar_variable_dcha
  select top (100000)
    replace (cast(NEWID() as varchar(100)), '-','')
    + REPLICATE ('a',200-32)
  from pedidos
  cross join detalles_de_pedidos

  print cast (@i as varchar(100))

  set@i = @i + 1

end
```

Comment: ok me parece perfecto edito mi pregunta, gracias.

Comment: ¿Si pones al inicio del todo: `delimiter //` y al final del todo: `//
delimiter ;` sigue dando error?  Ver más detalles [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68082/29967).