# Query de MySQL con un while y otra query dentro

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

Planteo aquí nua cuestión que he consultado en otros sitios y nadie me ha sabido responder. Soy novato en PHP y MySQL, y estoy haciendo mis pinitos. Me acabo de encontrar con un caso bastante frecuente, que es el de una query que lleva a un while, dentro del cual hay otra query. Si tienen el SQL dentro del PHP todo bien; pero en cuanto pongo las querys en procedimientos almacenados en la base de datos, la segunda deja de funcionar.

Un ejemplo muy simple que se puede contrastar:

```
// PRIMERA QUERY
$result_1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
if($result_1){
    while ($row_1 = $result_1->fetch_object()){
        $id_1 = $row_1->id;
        echo "<b>id_1: ".$id_1."</b><br />";
        // SEGUNDA QUERY
        $result_2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
        if($result_2){
            while ($row_2 = $result_2->fetch_object()){
                $id_2 = $row_2->id;
                echo "id_2: ".$id_2."<br />";
            }
            $result_2->close();
            $connection->next_result();
        }
    }
    $result_1->close();
    $connection->next_result();
}
```

Así funciona a la perfección, y el resultado es este:

```
id_1: 1
id_2: 1
id_2: 2
id_2: 3
id_2: 4
id_2: 5
id_1: 2
id_2: 1
id_2: 2
id_2: 3
id_2: 4
id_2: 5
id_1: 3
id_2: 1
id_2: 2
id_2: 3
id_2: 4
id_2: 5
etc.
```

Ahora creo un procedimiento en la base de datos:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure()
BEGIN
SELECT * from user;
END
```

Y entonces digamos que dejo la primera query con el SQL y la segunda con una llamada a procedimiento:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
[…]
$result_2 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
[…]
```

También funciona a la perfección, mismo resultado.

Peeeero si pongo la primera query con una llamada al procedimiento y la segunda con el SQL dentro:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
[…]
$result_2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
[…]
```

O si pongo las dos querys con llamadas a procedimientos:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
[…]
$result_2 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
[…]
```

Entonces la segunda query falla y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
id_1: 1
id_1: 2
id_1: 3
etc.
```

En resumen: siempre que la primera query tenga el SQL dentro, todo bien; pero si le pones una llamada a un procedimiento, la segunda query va a fallar.

Me parece tan simple y básico que no entiendo cómo puede fallar. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Casi seguro que es un problema de delimitadores. Si agregas esto al inicio de la procedure: `delimiter //`  y al final esto: `//
delimiter ;` debería funcionar. Ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68082/29967)  y también [la doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) de MySQL. También a la query _normal_ le pondría un punto y coma al final. Algo así: `"SELECT * FROM user;"`

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estás usando la librería mysqli:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
[…]
$result_2 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()") or die('Error en llamada: '. $connection->errno . ' - ' . $connection->error);
```

Probablemente el mensaje de error será respecto a liberar resultados antes de llamar otro procedimiento almacenado; recuerdo haber leído acerca de esta limitante, pero no encuentro ahora la documentación.

Respuesta corta: No puedes llamar un segundo procedimiento almacenado hasta que liberes el primero y, por tanto, no puedes anidarlos.

En todo caso, siempre es mala idea anidar consultas de esta forma y habría que buscar la opción para obtener todos los datos con una sola consulta, ya sea usando JOIN, UNION u otra que se me escape de momento.

Answer (score 0):

No se si se considera solución decirte que lo que pides no se puede hacer. 
Te lo voy a argumentar:
Llevo varios años(+5) en este mundo y nunca he podido llevarlo a cabo.

En PHP usamos un objeto que hace referencia a MySql, yo normalmente le llamo $link.

Pues bien, si hacemos un `var_dump` de `$link` vemos el estado actual de la base de datos, te dice querys por minuto, medias, etc...

Pues si hacemos esto cuando llamamos al procedure lo que veremos es un error.
Este error viene a decirnos que la no está sincronizada la base de datos y no puede usarse.

Pruébalo tu mismo y lo verás.

Esto pasa, por que el procedure es más lento que un insert o un update y el bucle sigue corriendo aunque el procedure no a terminado.

Para que quede claro, lo que estoy diciendo es que en un bucle los procedures se quedan pillados.

A modo de parche yo hice un sleep, pero es un parche.

Espero que esto te sirva, y te ayude a seguir avanzando.

Un saludo.